# mdc closes all nested dialogs instead of the active dialog

Tags: mdc, material-components, mdc-components

I try to open a `mdc-dialog` inside a `mdc-dialog`. When closing the second dialog, material-components-web closes both dialogs, instead of returning back to the underlying dialog (first dialog). See the example on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwWEQx).

Is that a bug or do I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing the source code of `mdc-dialog` I'm pretty sure, that it is a bug. Just opened a new bug on [github for material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/1506)